# Grep word boundaries

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Accorging to GNU documentation:

```
‘\<’ Match the empty string at the beginning of word.
‘\>’ Match the empty string at the end of word.
```

My /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
/dev/sdb1       /media/fresh      ext2   defaults     0 0
```

I want grep to return TRUE/FALSE for the existence of /media/fresh. I tried to use `\<` and `\>` but it didn't work. Why?

```
egrep '\</media/fresh\>' /etc/fstab
```

## Workaround:

```
egrep '[[:blank:]]/media/fresh[[:blank:]]' /etc/fstab
```

But it looks uglier.

My grep is 2.5.1

Comment: I suppose `/` is not considered a word character, so regex won't match -- ["\b matches before and after an alphanumeric sequence" is more exact than saying "before and after a word"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`\<` and `\>` match empty string at the begin and end of a word respectively and only word constituent characters are:

```
[[:alnum:]_]
```

From `man grep`:

```
Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

So, your Regex is failing because `/` is not a valid word constituent character.

Instead as you have spaces around, you can use `-w` option of `grep` to match a word:

```
grep -wo '/media/fresh' /etc/fstab
```

**Example:**

```
$ grep -wo '/media/fresh' <<< '/dev/sdb1       /media/fresh      ext2   defaults     0 0'
/media/fresh
```

Comment: I figures as much after I posted my Question. Any suggestion for what I want to achieve?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez Check my edits..

Answer (score 5):

This problem with `\<` (and also`\b`) applies not only to `/`, but to all non-word characters. (i.e. characters other than `[[:alnum:]]` and `_`. )

The problem is that the regex engine will always bypass a non-word character like `/` when searching for the next anchor `\<`. 
That's why you should not put non-word characters like `/` right after `\<`. 
If you do, by construction, nothing will match.

An alternative to the `-w` option of grep, would be something like this:

```
egrep "(^|\W)/media/fresh($|\W)"
```