# Is it possible to use grep to pick up only full words?

Tags: linux, grep

When I use the grep command, all occurrences of a word are picked up, even if they are part of other words. For example, if I use grep to find occurrences of the word 'the' it will also highlight 'the' in 'theatre'

Is there a way to adapt the grep command so that it only picks up full words, not part of words?

Comment: Give a try with -w option (might require also -E)

Comment: This similar to  [grep-word-boundaries (question) 281938](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281938/grep-word-boundaries)

Comment: grep RTFM $( answers )

Comment: See also [how to match exact subdomain with grep ignoring others](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/314283)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 -w, --word-regexp
              Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
              words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
              at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
              constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
              of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
              Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
              underscore.
```

from `man grep`

Comment: This is the ultimate answer. Otherwise you should go with something like this: `searchword='the'; grep -E "^$searchword\s|\s($searchword)\s|\s$searchword$|^$searchword$" textfile.txt
`

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha Less than that would do: `\<searchword\>`

Answer (score 11):

Also you can use this:

```
echo "this is the theater" |grep --color '\bthe\b'
```

For one word is the same with -w.
But if you need to search multiple patterns you can use the \b, otherwise all patterns will be treated as words if -w is in use.

For example :

```
grep -w -e 'the' -e 'lock'
```

will highlight the and lock but not keylock /padlock etc.

With \b you can treat each -e pattern differently.

[Test it here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNU5DS05DZ000OTA).

Answer (score 6):

You can test the presence of the beginning (resp. end) of a word with the marker `\<` (resp. `\>`).

Thus,

```
grep "\<the\>" << .
the cinema
a cinema
the theater
a theater
breathe
.
```

gives

```
the cinema
the theater
```