# grep: end of word delimiter not working?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Why in the following `(e)grep` attempts, `egrep` is unable to identify the end-of-word delimiter? (`b`)?

```
$ echo -n "my-pc is beautiful" | egrep  'my-pc\b'
my-pc is beautiful
/home/pkaramol
$ echo -n "my-pc-vol2 is beautiful" | egrep  'my-pc\b'
my-pc-vol2 is beautiful
```

Same are the results with plain `grep`?

Comment: Hyphen is a non-word character, so there is a word boundary after `my-pc` in both cases. See related [Grep word boundaries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281938/grep-word-boundaries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It identifies it fine but `grep` and `egrep` print the entire line of a match unless the `-o` option is used:

> -o, --only-matching
>
> Prints only the matching part of the lines.

I think you want:

```
$ echo -n "my-pc is beautiful" | egrep -o 'my-pc\b'
my-pc
```

---

A word boundary is any non-word character.  The word characters are: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.  Therefore `-` is not a word character.

Comment: Yes but my question is why in the second case it performs a match, whilst there is not `my-pc[endofword]` pattern

Comment: @pkaramol: See my update.

Comment: right, that seems to be the issue, thx.